# Rust: преобразование обобщённого типа в конкретный

Tags: generics, rust, преобразование-типов

Собственно код:

```
extern crate num_traits;

pub trait DigitCount {
    fn decimal_digit_count(&self) -> usize;
}

impl <T: PartialOrd + num_traits::Zero + Into<f64>> DigitCount for T {
    fn decimal_digit_count (&self) -> usize {
        if self.is_zero() {
            1
        } else {
            self.into().abs().log10().trunc() as usize + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Метод `decimal_digit_count` должен вызываться для любого целого значения и возвращать количество десятичных разрядов в нём:

```
println!("{}", 123u64.decimal_digit_count());
```

Вопрос: как правильно записать преобразование `T` → `f64` для последующего вызова методов `abs`, `log10`, `trunc`? В текущем виде компилятор требует аннотацию типа для `into()`, но если её подставить (`into::<T>()`), то говорит, что ожидается 0 параметров типов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У самого метода и правда нет типового параметра, потому что он есть у типажа:

```
pub trait Into<T> {
    fn into(self) -> T;
}
```

Первый вариант исправления - просто явно указать через промежуточную переменную какой тип мы в итоге хотим получить:

```
let f: f64 = self.into();
f.abs().log10().trunc() as usize + 1
```

([playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=04842cf1c32ff85276e39e2a3f1bb38b&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

Второй вариант - использовать UFCS форму вызова метода с явным обозначением `T` у типажа:

```
Into::<f64>::into(self).abs().log10().trunc() as usize + 1
```

([playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1bf50ba2121ff7487e41a5c7d5fba555&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

> Метод decimal_digit_count должен вызываться для любого целого значения и возвращать количество десятичных разрядов в нём

На всякий случай еще добавлю что преобразование в `f64` реализовано не для всех целых типов. Такое преобразование обязано всегда заканчиваться успехом, что невозможно, например, для `u64` или `i128` из-за невозможности вместить весь диапазон значений.

Comment: Ага, спасибо! (Жаль репутация не позволяет плюсануть).
А если надо принудительно привести в f64, пусть и с потерей точности?

Comment: @Haio если надо принудительно - то проще всего было бы делать это снаружи функции через оператор `as` и просто f64 принимать. Если же обязательно нужно приводить внутри обобщенной функции - боюсь мне в голову приходит только вариант с реализацией своего типажа для всех нужных типов (может на crates.io даже есть что-то такое уже, но я не в курсе).

Comment: Можно попробовать немного другой подход еще: отказаться от преведения к f64 и работать в обобщенной функции только через обобщающие типажи (и их функции) из пакета https://docs.rs/num .

Comment: В чате подсказывают что есть типаж https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.5/num_traits/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html , который как раз делает `as` в нужный тип с урезанием "лишней" точности.